# Apache Pig: merge nested bags to one bag

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How can I merge a nested bag in Pig?

like

```
{{item1, item2}, {item3, item4}, {item5, item6}}
```

to

```
{item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6}
```

Comment: Tried `FLATTEN`?

Answer (score 0):

Just calling on flatten on multiple bags would create a cross-product.
For your case, you probably need to convert the bags to tuple and then unnest the tuple by calling flatten. 
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/func.html#bagtotuple